# No se genera una de las columnas SQLite en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

En una de las tablas que tengo en mi base de datos no se genera una columna y no entiendo el motivo ya que la he creado exactamente igual que la otra y la otra no da fallos.

Cuando llamo al cursor que lee toda la tabla da el siguiente error que dice que una de las columnas no existe:

```
02-06 16:27:09.566 8044-8044/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas, PID: 8044
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Apagar (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _ID, Nombre, Apagar, Pagado, Folder FROM Usuarios
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
     at com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase.BaseDeDatos.getUsersData(BaseDeDatos.java:105)
     at com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.DataBase.BaseDeDatos.deleteFolder(BaseDeDatos.java:111)
     at com.app.a2.studio.android.aprendiendo.appmanejarcuentas.Screens.MainScreen$3.onClick(MainScreen.java:174)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Aquí tenéis la clase:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BaseDeDatos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "AppCuentas.db";

private static final String TABLE_FOLDERS = "Folders";

private static final String TF_COLOM_ID = "_ID";
private static final String TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS = "NumberUsers";
private static final String TF_COLOM_NAME = "Nombre";

private static final String StringTableFolders = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FOLDERS + " ("
        + TF_COLOM_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + TF_COLOM_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS + " INTEGER) ";

private static final String TABLE_USUARIOS = "Usuarios";
private static final String TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID = "_ID";
private static final String TU_COLOM_FOLDER = "Folder";
private static final String TU_COLOM_NAME = "Nombre";
private static final String TU_COLOM_APAGAR = "Apagar";
private static final String TU_COLOM_PAGADO = "Pagado";

private static final String StringTableUsuarios = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USUARIOS +" ("
        + TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + TU_COLOM_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + TU_COLOM_APAGAR + " INTEGER, "
        + TU_COLOM_PAGADO + " INTEGER, "
        + TU_COLOM_FOLDER + " INTEGER ) ";


public BaseDeDatos(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(StringTableFolders);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(StringTableUsuarios);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_FOLDERS);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + TABLE_USUARIOS);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}

public boolean addData(String name, int numberUsers){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valuesFolders = new ContentValues();

    valuesFolders.put(TF_COLOM_NAME, name);
    valuesFolders.put(TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS, numberUsers);

    long resultFolders = db.insert(TABLE_FOLDERS, null, valuesFolders);

    if(resultFolders == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean addData(int folder, String name, float aPagar, float pagado){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valuesUsuarios = new ContentValues();

    valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_FOLDER, folder);
    valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_NAME, name);
    valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_APAGAR, aPagar);
    valuesUsuarios.put(TU_COLOM_PAGADO, pagado);

    long resultUsuarios = db.insert(TABLE_USUARIOS, null, valuesUsuarios);

    if(resultUsuarios == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getAllFoldersData(){
    String folderColoms[] = {TF_COLOM_ID, TF_COLOM_NAME, TF_COLOM_NUMBER_USERS};
    Cursor c = this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_FOLDERS, folderColoms, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}

public Cursor getUsersData(){
    String usersColoms[] = {TU_COLOM_PRIMARY_ID, TU_COLOM_NAME, TU_COLOM_APAGAR, TU_COLOM_PAGADO, TU_COLOM_FOLDER};
    Cursor cursorUsers = this.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_USUARIOS, usersColoms, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursorUsers;
}

public Integer deleteFolder(String folderID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = getUsersData();
    Integer users = 1;

    if(c.getCount() != 0){
          users = db.delete(TABLE_USUARIOS, "Folder = ?", new String[] { folderID });
    }

    Integer folders = db.delete(TABLE_FOLDERS, "_ID = ?", new String[] { folderID });
    if(users > 0){
        if(folders > 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

}

public Integer deleteUser(String userID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Integer user = db.delete(TABLE_USUARIOS, "_ID = ?" , new String[] { userID });

    return user;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

hola disculpa tienes un pequeño problema de Sintaxis

```
    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

lo debes reemplazar por

```
    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

de todos modos tu query para crear la tabla es la siguiente :

```
    CREATE TABLE   Usuarios
    (
            ID      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
            Nombre  TEXT, 
            Apagar  INTEGER, 
            Pagado  INTEGER, 
            Folder  INTEGER 
     ) ;
```